# Does ActiveMQ-CPP 3.9.4 Support OpenSSL 1.1.0?

Tags: openssl, activemq-cpp

I am attempting to build the latest version of Apache ActiveMQ-CPP, which is 3.9.4.  I have built both of the required dependencies, APR and OpenSSL.  For OpenSSL, this is version 1.1.0f.  I am able to build all 4 of the configurations without SSL support (Debug, DebugDLL, Release, ReleaseDLL).  However, attempting to build anything with SSL support results in a number of errors:

> ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp(186): error C3861: 'CRYPTO_malloc_init': identifier not found
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(667): error C2027: use of undefined type 'X509_extension_st'
>   C:\OpenSource\OpenSSL\1.1.0f\include\openssl/x509.h(79): note: see declaration of 'X509_extension_st'
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(667): error C2227: left of '->value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(667): error C2227: left of '->data' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(670): error C2027: use of undefined type 'X509_extension_st'
>   C:\OpenSource\OpenSSL\1.1.0f\include\openssl/x509.h(79): note: see declaration of 'X509_extension_st'
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(670): error C2227: left of '->value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(670): error C2227: left of '->length' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(670): error C2660: 'ASN1_item_d2i': function does not take 3 arguments
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(671): error C2027: use of undefined type 'X509_extension_st'
>   C:\OpenSource\OpenSSL\1.1.0f\include\openssl/x509.h(79): note: see declaration of 'X509_extension_st'
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(671): error C2227: left of '->value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(671): error C2227: left of '->length' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(671): error C2198: 'X509V3_EXT_D2I': too few arguments for call
>   ..\src\main\decaf\internal\net\ssl\openssl\OpenSSLSocket.cpp(671): error C2198: 'X509V3_EXT_I2V': too few arguments for call

The release notes haven't mentioned anything about OpenSSL since support was added in 3.2.0.  However, the README.txt file included with the ActiveMQ-CPP 3.9.4 download states:

> If you wish to use the SSL Transport then you will need to have OpenSSL and its includes installed on your system.  We recommend that you use version 1.0.0 or higher for best performance and security, but version from 0.9.8 are also known to work.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606619/apache-2-4-23-undefined-reference-to-crypto-malloc-init) seems to indicate that my first error (see above) implies that OpenSSL 1.1.0 isn't supported by ActiveMQ-CPP.  However, there doesn't appear to be an issue submitted on the [ActiveMQ-CPP Jira site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQCPP-439?jql=project%20%3D%20AMQCPP%20AND%20text%20~%20openssl%20ORDER%20BY%20cf%5B10010%5D%20ASC) about lack of OpenSSL 1.1.0 support, and their own documentation clearly states that I should be able to use "version 1.0.0 or higher".

Does anyone know whether ActiveMQ-CPP 3.9.4 supports OpenSSL 1.1.0?

Comment: From one of the answers in the cited question... see [Apache Issue 60061 - OpenSSL 1.1.0 support](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60061).

Comment: @jww That question, to which I provided a link, is for a different product.  The link you posted is for an issue reported with Apache httpd-2, not Apache ActiveMQ-CPP.

Comment: Down-voter care to comment?  Any recommendations as to how the question can be improved?

Comment: This *may* be resolved in ActiveMQ-CPP 3.9.5: See [Jira ticket AMQCPP-623](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQCPP-623?jql=project%20%3D%20AMQCPP%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.9.5).  This issue is vague, but it was opened by the very person who answered this question a few months after that answer was posted.

Comment: @TimBish confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143202/failed-to-build-activemq-cms-3-9-5-with-openssl-1-1-1) that ActiveMQ-CPP 3.9.5 still does not support OpenSSL 1.1.1.  It seems that ActiveMQ-CPP is no longer maintained.  [QPid Proton](https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/releases) is a better supported C++ messaging client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client doesn't support OpenSSL 1.1.0 as reported on the ActiveMQ [mailing lists](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/activemq-cpp-3-9-4-fails-to-build-fedora-rawhide-openssl-1-1-0e-related-td4724037.html#a4728754).  I don't think anyone bothered to open an issue to that effect though.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to where you found that information in the ActiveMQ mailing list?  I wasn't able to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that v3.9.5 on RHEL8/OracleLinux8/Centos8 will now compile properly if you have the right openssl and devel libraries installed.

https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/download/395-release

yum install openssl-devel apr apr-devel apr-util-openssl openssl-pkcs11

I did it with the gcc-toolset-10 but other versions of GCC should work as well.

I also had the ssl compat libraries installed but I don't believe those are necessary: compat-openssl10

Installed OpenSSL version is: openssl-1.1.1g-15.el8_3.x86_64