# Failed to build activemq CMS 3.9.5 with OpenSSL 1.1.1

Tags: openssl, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

Readme.txt for ActiveMQ CPP library version 3.9.5 states

### 1.3 OpenSSL

> If you wish to use the SSL Transport then you will need to have
>   OpenSSL and its includes installed on your system.  We recommend that
>   you use version 1.0.0 or higher for best performance and security, but
>   version from 0.9.8 are also known to work.

I'm trying to build activemq cms 3.9.5 with OpenSSL 1.1.1 using Visual Studio project (included into activemq-cpp 3.9.5 distribution) and looks like  CRYPTO_malloc_init() is removed  from OpenSSL 1.1.1, such that I'm having compilation error in OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp

```
#ifdef HAVE_OPENSSL
    // General library initialization.
#ifdef WIN32
    CRYPTO_malloc_init();
#endif
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

...
while OpenSSL 1.1.1 has define another macro

```
#define OPENSSL_malloc_init() \
    CRYPTO_set_mem_functions(CRYPTO_malloc, CRYPTO_realloc, CRYPTO_free)
```

I found the following 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005827/does-activemq-cpp-3-9-4-support-openssl-1-1-0/55131365#55131365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005827/does-activemq-cpp-3-9-4-support-openssl-1-1-0/55131365#55131365,) 
but I'm not clear whether it was addressed and I'm having the problem to build it properly or OpenSSL 1.1.1 is not actually supported by version 3.9.5? 
Any help or clarification would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.1.1 is not supported in that version of the CMS client and so mostly likely won't allow the client to build, and if it does build it'd likely fail.  The CMS client is not actively being developed so I would look at alternate client libraries such as an AMQP client for the [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) project for instance.

Comment: Thank you Tim for clarification! This is very unfortunate as per [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/source/) LTS for 1.0.2 series will continue to be supported only until 31/12/2019  and all users of 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 are encouraged to upgrade to 1.1.1 as soon as possible. By not supporting it many products relying on CMS client will be left "hung out to dry"...

Comment: The Qpid clients will support more current OpenSSL libraries and the broker supports AMQP

Comment: Is there any guide for migrating from CMS client API to Qpid client? Is any performance or configuration impact on switching from Openwire to AMQP?